# Why Maven report's "Checksum validation failed, no checksums available from the repository"?

Tags: maven, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maven-plugin

I am trying to run an Azure pipeline with third-party jars files. In pom, I pointed them to the local repo itself.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
            <id>data-local</id>
            <name>data</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

When I try to run the pipeline, I see the checksum validation error in the logs.

Error Log:

```
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:210)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:195)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:515)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:264)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---     at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] ---                    
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] --- [WARNING] Checksum validation failed, no checksums available from data-local for file:///home/vsts/work/1/s/repo/com/streamserve/jstrscas/16.6.2_GA_327/jstrscas-16.6.2_GA_327.pom
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread] --- Downloaded from data-local: file:///home/vsts/work/1/s/repo/com/streamserve/jstrscas/16.6.2_GA_327/jstrscas-16.6.2_GA_327.pom (410 B at 22 kB/s)
2022-11-15 07:51:01 UTC DEBUG [main-Executable_Stream_Thread]
```

I've taken the following steps:

1. Installed the project test on the local repository Maven with the command: `mvn clean install -DcreateChecksum=true`

Comment: Why do you have configured `<url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>` this? What is the need for this?

Comment: Hi, can you try whether the Maven project runs successfully in local machine? If so, could you tell what command do you run, do you use the Maven@3 task in Azure devops pipelines? Could you kindly share the task definition? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Bharath, have the issue already been resolved? If so, could you kindly share the resolution here? It may help others who may meet the issue in the future.